Will it be beneficial to my research funding application if I try to explain the reasons of the relatively few citations of my works?
My papers have on average 4 citations despite having been presented at A-rated conferences or published at A-rated journals.
To give you a perspective the number of citations of the average paper on my field is probably not much higher.
Will it be beneficial to my research funding application if I try to explain the reasons of the relatively few citations of my works?

Do you know the reason?

And if this is the norm in the field, why bother explaining?

Why do you keep trying to find excuses for what you think is bad performance? Your applications should convince with good performance, I don’t think the strategy underlying your recent questions is useful. All you are doing is drawing attention to the fact you consider your own performance inadequate.

@Buffy I can't be completely certain but I can give some speculations.

@Sursula Because most of the people with that citation count probably don't get any funding.

@MisterMiyagi Since I haven't really written any research proposal before I am unsure as to what to include in it. By reading the responses of other academics and looking at the sentiment of their statements I get a better idea as to what to include and what not in it.

Why would anyone downvote this question?

No, I wouldn't do this. Citation counts are not the be-all-end-all, and you can make a good case for your work without mentioning them at all. This is a case where bringing up a potential criticism will actually draw unnecessary attention to it.
In fact, even if you had high citation counts, you generally wouldn't point that out explicitly in your proposal, as this would come across oddly.

It will be beneficial only if the reasons are both good and non-obvious.
Examples:

My papers have relatively few citations because they are new.

This is a good reason, but is obvious and not helpful to mention.

My papers have relatively few citations because the Lizardmen control academia and they have issued a secret boycott of my work.

This is a non-obvious reason, but isn’t a good one.
Examples of good, non-obvious reasons:

Can’t think of any (but I’m not ruling out the possibility that some such reasons may exist). If you want to tell us the reason we can comment on whether they belong to this category.


Edit: you clarified in a comment that the reason is that

My paper has a low citation count because it came out around the same time as a major survey paper on the subject and for some reason it wasn't included in it. Most of the subsequent papers and surveys seem to cite the works(that were published before the survey) based on what's included in that survey.

I don't think that's a good reason, and indeed it's not even clear that this is a "reason" at all. You're saying that the survey paper doesn't cite your paper "for some reason" and that the subsequent papers "seem to" have only cited "based on what's included in that survey". So, you're essentially admitting to not actually knowing the reason why the survey paper didn't cite your work; and to also not knowing the reason why the follow-up papers didn't cite it, except that you're speculating the reason might be because they're relying on the survey paper. This is a completely unconvincing explanation.
The bottom line is, I agree with what others have said. Your research proposal should focus on what's good about your (past and future) research, not on making excuses. No one cares about why you have relatively few citations. Moreover, if your research is actually impressive and you do a good job of explaining why, then likely no one would care even about the fact that it has relatively few citations, let alone about the reasons for this.
Conversely, if you fail to make a convincing case that your research is good, your discussion about the low citation count won't impress anyone. So the answer to your original question is no, it's not beneficial.

Here is a reason that might be deemed good: My paper has a low citation count because  it came out around the same time as a major survey paper on the subject and for some reason it wasn't included in it. Most of the subsequent papers and surveys seem to cite the works(that were published before the survey) based on what's included in that survey.

If it came out around the same time, how would the survey authors have known about your paper? Another excuse I guess…

@Kupp That's not a good reason. That's at best neutral if you go for the obvious case of your paper coming out after the survey paper looked for papers. Otherwise, you need something much better than "for some reason it wasn't included" because there the obvious reason is that it wasn't notable/good enough.

@JonCuster They may not have known about it. But this probably effected its citation count.

@MisterMiyagi They either saw the paper and decided they shouldn't change the survey to include it perhaps because it was my first paper and had zero citations back then or they didn't see the paper. Since they included works of similar scale and of similarly rated journals I doubt that it was the quality of the work the critical factor here.

@Kupp - you keep focusing on things outside your control. What is your proposed research and why is it new, novel, and impactful? That is what you focus on, not grasping at straws for excuses.

@Kupp "Since they included works of similar scale and of similarly rated journals I doubt that it was the quality of the work the critical factor here." Erm, seriously, I would not doubt that. No intention to dismiss your work specifically (since frankly I don’t know it) but if someone tells me the review authors went the extra mile to include similar papers but not theirs - yes, quality would be my absolute first guess then. The absolute best reading here would be that it’s not bad but also not significantly different from the others. None of that is a good message.

@MisterMiyagi The solution which I was improving was in a set of solutions which were considered roughly equally important by the survey. The type of improvement to that solution was the same as those of several other solutions of the same importance which were included. You could argue that my techniques to reach the improvement  were different and inferior that those of the other improvements but I doubt it.
